# Manga where a boy and his house are transported to a magical world and he is extremely powerful there

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for this manga in which this boy wakes up and he and his house are transported in a magical world. He is so powerful that he blows away dragons and these girls come to face him and they get defeated instantly when he shouts.

Comment: Interesting, but there's not much to go off here, can you please check out [How to ask a good (anime/manga) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11874/21267) for ideas on what info to add. Definitely try to include some dates, like when did you read it? When might it have been published? etc.

Comment: I actually have no idea I forgot. It's just goes in and out of my mind

Comment: The answer provided by shufly seems to fit the description.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you are looking for [Ore no Ie ga Maryoku Spot datta Ken – Sundeiru dake de Sekai Saikyou](https://mangadex.org/title/27467/ore-no-ie-ga-maryoku-spot-datta-ken-sundeiru-dake-de-sekai-saikyou), or *My House is a Magic Power Spot - Just by Living there I Become the Strongest in the World.*

The main character and his house are summoned to another world while he was asleep.  He wakes up to the women who summoned the house outside. Then he shouts at them to shut up, which causes all of them to fly backwards into trees, after which they all run away. The women then encounter a dragon, and run back towards the house. The main character then yells at them to let him sleep, which defeats the dragon.

Just a warning, the first two chapters at least appear to keep having the women piss themselves in fear, and the second shout shreds all their clothing so it is probably NSFW.

Comment: shuffy dude you're outshining me. every single time i decide to answer a question in manga-story identification i see your answer :D leave some to me pls <3

Comment: @WukongWannaBe give it some time. new questions will pop up and you'll probably get to answer before me. you can probably look through some more and see all the ones Jenayah and Karaelfte answered before i could.

Comment: yeah they are fast too. well who knows, maybe ill get there too one day :D

Comment: @WukongWannaBe Having too much time on my hands is a big help