# Manga where the main character and his house get isekaied

Tags: story-identification, manga

In the manga the MC is a gamer staying at home. He hears shouting outside and goes to check it out (shout at them for shouting) and discovered a group trying to break in and so starts throwing stuff.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [Manga where a boy and his house are transported to a magical world and he is extremely powerful there](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232798/manga-where-a-boy-and-his-house-are-transported-to-a-magical-world-and-he-is-ext)

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Full colour thanks in advance

Comment: What happens after he's isekai'd?

Comment: If I'm remembering right he finds out he is in an ancient wuxia story (a very famous one

Answer (score 3):

Is it [Regarding My House Being a Magic Power Spot: Just by Living There I Become the Strongest in the World](https://myanimelist.net/manga/115515/Ore_no_Ie_ga_Maryoku_Spot_Datta_Ken__Sundeiru_dake_de_Sekai_Saikyou) (aka Ore no Ie ga Maryoku Spot Datta Ken: Sundeiru dake de Sekai Saikyou)?

> Living carefree at home is the greatest shortcut—my house is the world’s greatest Magic Power Spot. That being the case, both my house and I were summoned to another world by some guys who were aiming for it. However, I’ve been living in this place for many years and my body is, apparently, abnormally overflowing with magic. Due to some unforeseen circumstances by those guys who summoned me, they quickly ran away. Be that as it may, there are still some ill-mannered people who covet the magic leaking out of my house. I won’t give up my house to those people! I’m going to wield my power as I please!
>
> (Source: Shueisha, translated)

Comment: No thanks for trying